# How can I escape forward slashes in a user input variable in bash?

Tags: bash, variables, escaping, user-input

I'm working on a script to make setting up a Statamic site more efficient. The problem I'm running into is that the variable I'm using to replace a string in a file has unescaped forward slashes and is user input. How can I make sure that `_site_url: http://statamic.com` will become `_site_url: http://example.com`?

The code below will work as long as there are no forward slashes present.

```
echo "What's your site URL? Don't forget the protocol (ex. http://)!"
read -e SITE_URL

echo "%s/_site_url: http:\/\/statamic.com/_site_url: $SITE_URL/g
w
q
" | ex _config/settings.yaml
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the delimiter in your `ex` command. We can put anything we'd like instead, I use `@` here :

Try doing this :

```
 sed -i "s@_site_url: http://statamic.com/_site_url: $SITE_URL@g" _config/settings.yaml
```

Or with your `ex` command :

```
echo "What's your site URL? Don't forget the protocol (ex. http://)!"
read -e SITE_URL

echo "%s@_site_url: http://statamic.com@_site_url: $SITE_URL@g
w
q
" | ex _config/settings.yaml
```

Comment: Added `ex` command solution too. Tested ok on my `archlinux` box.

Comment: Why do you use `ex` and not `sed` or `perl` ?

Comment: sed creates a new file, so I'd have to delete it as well.

perl didn't work when I tried another it for another problem in the script.

ex doesn't create a new file.

Comment: Both `perl` & `sed` have `-i` switch, do you know that ? It creates a newfile yes, but in the background, exactly like `ex`. Try `strace -f -s 1000 -e trace=file bash script.ex` to figure it out.

Comment: From what I read about the `-i` switch, it's an extension for both, so I don't want to rely on that. This script will be shared with others.

Answer (score 8):

Since you specifically mentioned bash instead of Bourne shell or generic Unix shell, I'd recommend using Bash's built in search/replace feature:

```
echo "What's your site URL? Don't forget the protocol (ex. http://)!"
read -e SITE_URL

echo Escaped URL: ${SITE_URL//\//\\\/}
```